# How to find the probability of each element in a array getting a certain random variable?

Tags: java, arrays, statistics, probability

I created an array called new array and assigned the vales so the first node in the array is 0 and the rest is 1.

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
arr[0] = 0;
 for (int m = 1; m < 10; m++) {
         arr[m] = 1;
    }
```

Then I did a loop to assign a random variable between 0 and 1 to it

```
for(int i = 0;i < 100; i++){
    U = rnd.nextInt(2);
   int j = rnd.nextInt(10);
    arr[j] = U;
}
```

I am trying to write a code to find the probability that each element in this array gets assigned the number 0 at least once. The probabilty it will get assigned 0 is .1?

Answer (score 0):

In your code the probability depends by the nextInt function implementation.
So, you have to study the random function that you use to determinate the final proability.

Answer (score 0):

- For the first element: it's necessarily set to zero at the very beginning, so the probability is **1**.
- For the second element:

  - In each loop iteration:

    - Every element is equally likely to be chosen, meaning that the second element has a one-in-ten chance (probability 0.1) of being chosen.
    - The chosen element is equally likely to be set to either zero or one, meaning that it has a one-in-two chance (probability 0.5) of being set to zero.
    - The events "the second is chosen" and "the chosen element is set to zero" are independent, so we can multiply their probabilities to get the probability of the event "the second element is set to zero" (meaning "the second element is chosen and the chosen element is set to zero"): 0.1 × 0.5 = 0.05.
    - This means that the event "the second element is *not* set to zero" has probability 1 − 0.05 = 0.95.
  - Overall:

    - Since there are 100 iterations, and they're all mutually independent, the event "the second element is *never* set to zero" (meaning "in every single iteration, the second element is not set to zero") has probability 0.95<sup>100</sup> ≈ 0.00592.
    - This means that the event "the second element is set to zero *at least once*" has probability **1 − 0.95<sup>100</sup> ≈ 0.994**.
- The third, fourth, etc. elements are equivalent to the second element — I just chose the second element for convenience — so they, too, each have a probability of **1 − 0.95<sup>100</sup> ≈ 0.994** of getting set to zero at least once.